# Creating a 15x15 Square Grid in a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a WinForms user control and I'm trying to draw 15 rows of 15 squares. If the size of the control changes, then the squares should get smaller, but still have 15 rows of 15 squares, like this pattern:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

I am trying to use `ClientSize.Width` and `ClientSize.Height` to divide by 15, but its not coming out exactly right. Any help with this algorithm would be appreciated!

This is in C#, by the way.

Here is the code I have:

Graphics g = e.Graphics;

```
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);

        if (ClientSize.Width > ClientSize.Height)
        {
            int ndx = (int)Math.Ceiling(ClientSize.Height/15f);
            for (int x = 0; x < ClientSize.Width; x += ndx)
            {
                for (int y=0 ; y<ClientSize.Height; y+=ndx)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x + ndx, y);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x, y + ndx);
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            int ndx = (int)Math.Ceiling(ClientSize.Width / 15f);
            for (int x = 0; x < ClientSize.Width; x += ndx)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < ClientSize.Height; y += ndx)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x + ndx, y);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, y, x, y + ndx);
                }
            }
        }
        g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Well, what does "not coming out exactly right" mean? (*Useful* problem description *and* code, please)

Comment: "Not coming out exactly right" means that as I resize the user control, there is usually an extra line or lack of a line at the end

Comment: Unless the division is perfect there will be a little difference. However, it sounds like it is caused by a rounding error. I would recommend always shooting on the *low* side by rounding down, then using that (integral) value as the multiplier in the loop. Remember that each grid cell should likely include it's bottom-right edge (when drawing) and the top-left edge of the entire grid should be accounted for in the initial total size calculations.

Comment: When they're equal, you shouldn't be using the value of `15`. Just remove the last `if` and change the second `if` to an `else`.

Comment: Same result Minitech. The control's size is 440x324 (width by height) and at that height and width, I'm getting an extra line at the bottom.

Comment: @icemanind: Draw at `Math.Ceiling(n)` instead of `n`, it should fix your problem.

Comment: @minitech: I just posted my revised code. Your latest suggestion took out the extra line, but now the last row is rectangle instead of a perfect square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that your grid will only fit if the container's width and height are exactly divisible by 15.  Try rounding down.

```
const int ColumnCount = 15;
const int RowCount    = 15;
int cellwidth  = (int)Math.Floor(ClientSize.Width  / ColumnCount);
int cellheight = (int)Math.Floor(ClientSize.Height / RowCount   );
```

After you draw your grid, explicitly blackout the area past the last row and column.  You'll have a thick black border but it will clearly define the 15x15 grid.

If you want to avoid the black border, force the `ClientSize.Width` and `.Height` to be multiples of `ColumnCount` and `RowCount` respectively.

Comment: Can I intercept the resize event of the control and "snap" the resize to a multiple of 15? If I can, this solution might work

Comment: I was under the impression `int / int -> int`, always truncating (rounding-towards-zero)...

Comment: @icemanind, yes.  Just add an event handler for `Me.Resize` or `Me.SizeChanged` and set the `ClientSize` there.  You might get some graphical flicker during resizing.  I haven't worked out how to avoid this.

Comment: @pst, I don't have a clue, so I won't assume so.  I'm used to VB.Net where `/` always produces a `double` result for most primitive data types.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a perfect square, it's much easier; if the control is wider than it is tall, divide the height into 15 and use that as the side of each square. If it is taller than it is wide, divide the width into 15 and use that as the side of each square.

Comment: I just posted code. I'm doing what you said I think, but its still coming out wrong. Like there will be an extra line near the bottom.